# Hide Everything in dropdown Search in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, people-search

I am working in SP2013, I have enterprise search. In the drop down I want to hide the "Everything" and "People" options.

Example:
In Site Collection Administrator Settings -> Enter a Search Center URL there we given the Enterprise search url like "search/pages" here I can able to see the dropdown options, also it was redirecting to osssresults with dropdown options.